# adjusting input element inside div

Tags: html, css

I have a main `<div>` inside which there are a **left** and **right** ones.
On the left one, I have an `<input type = "text">`.

my problem is that the width and height of the `<input>` element look larger than its container which is the left `<div>`.

please help me out with the input element.

[**DEMO**](http://jsbin.com/kejefawabo/edit?html,css,output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A native input has `padding` and `border` applied to it.

Add this to your `input` CSS:

```
border: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is because of the padding.

Just add these styles in your CSS:

```css
* {
    box-sizing:border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    -ms-box-sizing:border-box;
    -o-box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what you are looking for:

```
 box-sizing: border-box;
```

So your css should look like this:

```
.leftDiv input {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change height of input in css

```css
div.wrapper {
  width : 200px;
  height : 30px;
  background-color : red;
}

div.wrapper div.leftDiv {
  float: left;
  width : 30%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color : blue;
}

div.wrapper input[type = "text"] {
  float: left;
  width : 100%;
  height: 20px; 
}
div.wrapper div.rightDiv {
  float: right;
  width : 60%;
  height: 30px;
  background-color : yellow;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class = "wrapper">
   <div class ="leftDiv">
     <input type = "text" value = "1">
  </div>
  <div class = "rightDiv">
  </div>
</div>
  
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```css
div.wrapper {
  width : 200px;
  height : 20px;
  background-color : red;
}

div.wrapper div.leftDiv {
  float: left;
  width : 30%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color : blue;
}

div.wrapper input[type = "text"] {
  float: left;
  width : 100%;
  height: 20px; 
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
div.wrapper div.rightDiv {
  float: right;
  width : 60%;
  height: 20px;
  background-color : yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class = "wrapper">
   <div class ="leftDiv">
     <input type = "text" value = "1">
  </div>
  <div class = "rightDiv">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the height the height that's my idea

```
div.wrapper input[type="text"] {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: 14px;
}
```